# HTTP::Proxy: how to replace a whole html page

Tags: perl, http-proxy

I'm trying to use HTTP::Proxy to server 403 error for some specific domain. I already managed to modify headers, but the proxy continue to serve the original page.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
package Filters::Filter403;

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Proxy::HeaderFilter::simple;
use HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple;

our $header = HTTP::Proxy::HeaderFilter::simple->new (
    sub {
        $_[2]->code( 403 );
        $_[2]->message ( 'Forbidden' );
    }
);

our $body = HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple->new (
    sub {       
        $_[1] = \<<'HTML';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title><style type="text/css">
body { padding: 40pt; }
body, h1, h2, p { color: #333; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; }
div { width: 200px; background: #eee; padding: 2em; }
</style></head><body><div><h1>403</h1><h2>Forbidden</h2></div></body></html>
HTML
    }
);

1;
```

Here is the code from the main script where I'm calling this two filters, so you can have a better look:

```
use HTTP::Proxy qw(:log);
use Getopt::Long;

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib $Bin;

use Filters;
use HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::complete;

my $port = 3128;
my $fail_at;
my $outputfile = '/var/log/cvmfs-test/webproxy.output';
my $errorfile = '/var/log/cvmfs-test/webproxy.error';

my $ret = GetOptions ( "port=i" => \$port,
                       "fail=s" => \$fail_at );

my @fail_at = split(/,/, $fail_at);

# Opening file for log
open (LOG, '>>', $outputfile);

my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new;
$proxy->port( $port );
$proxy->logfh( *LOG );
$proxy->logmask( ALL );

if ($fail_at[0] ne 'all') {
    foreach my $url (@fail_at) {
        $proxy->push_filter(
            host => $url,
            response => HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::complete->new,
            response => $Filters::Filter403::header,
            response => $Filters::Filter403::body
        );
    }
}
else {
    $proxy->push_filter (
        response => HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::complete->new(),
        response => $Filters::Filter403::header,
        response => $Filters::Filter403::body
    );
}

my $pid = fork();

# Command for the forked process
if ( defined($pid) and $pid == 0 ) {
    open (my $errfh, '>', $errorfile);
    STDOUT->fdopen( \*$errfh, 'w' ) || die "Couldn't set STDERR to $errorfile: $!\n";
    $proxy->start;
}

# Command for the main script
unless ($pid == 0) {
    print "Proxy HTTP started on port $port with PID $pid.\n";
    print "You can read its output in $outputfile.\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Can you please help me?
I tried Daxim solution and I also tried to use `$ { $_[1] }` as documentation seems to suggest, but it didn't works.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can check wget -S to the proxy to see when content expires. If it's 10 years ahead, you would need to get into this proxy cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.
The problem is that every filter after `HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::complete->new` is executed with empty data. I found that loading an heavy page, my code were added multiple times.

Here is the working filter:

```
our $body = HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple->new (
    sub {
        my ( $self, $dataref, $message, $protocol, $buffer ) = @_;
        unless (defined ($buffer)){
            my $html = 
                    '<!DOCTYPE html>'.
                    '<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title><style type="text/css">'.
                    'body { padding: 40pt; }'.
                    'body, h1, h2, p { color: #333; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; }'.
                    'div { width: 200px; background: #eee; padding: 2em; }'.
                    '</style></head><body><div><h1>403</h1><h2>Forbidden</h2></div></body></html>';

            $$dataref = $html;
        }
    }
);
```

This way, the filter doesn't do anything unless $buffer is undef, i.e. when the whole response was received.

Answer (score 0):

See [HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::complete](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aProxy%3a%3aBodyFilter%3a%3acomplete).

```
$proxy->push_filter(
    response => HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::complete->new,
    response => HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple->new(sub {
        $_[1] = \<<'HTML';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title><style type="text/css">
body { padding: 40pt; }
body, h1, h2, p { color: #333; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; }
div { width: 200px; background: #eee; padding: 2em; }
</style></head><body><div><h1>403</h1><h2>Forbidden</h2></div></body></html>
HTML
    }),
);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working for me. I'm going to update the post with the code of the main script, so you can have a look there, too.

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you because I wouldn't without your suggestion of BodyFilter::complete.

Comment: I see the documentation could use some improvement; I'll propose a patch to BooK. I'm glad you figured out what you wanted, and it is okay to mark your own answer as accepted since it fits the question best.